# Rename an Excel table column using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

On a Sheet named "Resources", I have a table named RESOURCES that has a column named "Column name". How can I rename this column using VBA ?

I tried the following but it results in an error : `ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Resources").Range("RESOURCES[[#Headers];[Column Name]]").Value = "New name"`

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about

```
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Resources").ListObjects("RESOURCES").ListColumns("Column name").Name = "New column name"
```

Hope that helps